# AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute' error on connection.execute statement for select count *

Tags: python, mysql

I am taking some columns values from a table and inserting it in another table. I am getting error at select count * statement. Error says"AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'". Below are the code:

```
import mysql.connector

print("after import")

#def takesubtable():
run = mysql.connector
connection = run.connect(host="localhost", user="user", password="password", database="db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

query1 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tablename
(column1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 column2 DATE,
 .
 .
 column10 varchar(45));""" 

it = 1
cursor.execute(query1)

count = connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")

#insert values from 1 table to another table 
for i in count:
    inssql = insert into table2(columns_list) values(%s, ......, %s)
    val = select columns_list where column1 = {num}",it
    op = cursor.execute(inssql,val)
    it = it + 1

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Please help

Comment: `connection.execute` should be `cursor.execute`

Comment: You got it right the other 2 times, don't you see the difference?

Comment: I made the required changes. Now when I do "print(count)" after "count = connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")", I get None value

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  password="yourpassword"
)

query1 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tablename
(column1 INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 column2 DATE,
 .
 .
 column10 varchar(45));"""
it = 1

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute(query1)

count = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table")

for i in count:
    inssql = insert into table2(columns_list) values(%s, ......, %s)
    val = select columns_list where column1 = {num}",it
    op = cursor.execute(inssql,val)
    it = it + 1

cursor.close()
mydb.close()
```